# ipcRenderer not receiving the message from webContents.send (Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

In the main window of my program, I have a button that, if clicked, creates a new, additional window. When this new window finishes loading, I want to send a message to `ipcRenderer`; however, I have not been able so far to make `ipcRenderer` able to receive the message, even though the window is created successfully.

Here's a snippet of the code in `main.js`:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

ipcMain.handle('open-window', () => {
    const newWindow = createWindow();
    newWindow.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        newWindow.webContents.send('opened-window');
    });
});
```

Note that `createWindow` is a function that creates and returns a browser window.

And here's a snippet of the code in `preload.js`:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('openWindow').addEventListener('click', () => {
        ipcRenderer.invoke('open-window');
    });
});

ipcRenderer.on('opened-window', () => {
    console.log('received message!')
})
```

As you can see, I would expect to receive in the console the string `received message!` after the new window finishes loading; however, this is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `"opened-window"` to the new window you created, not the original one in which the button was pressed.

```js
newWindow.webContents.send('opened-window')
```

instead of `newWindow`, you need to refer to the window with the button and the `opened-window` handler

Comment: Hmm... I see what you are saying, but it is still not working. I tried printing something to terminal like this: `newWindow.on('did-finish-load', () => { console.log('print here') });`, but nothing is printed to the terminal. Interestingly, I see `print here` in the terminal if I use `ready-to-show` instead of `did-finish-load`, but I am not able to make `ipcRenderer` receive the message even with what you suggested.

Comment: @6cloud9 can you show the code in `createWindow` where you load the window?

Comment: Sure, I can, but it is a pretty simple function, actually. I just create a new instance of a `BrowserWindow`, where `nodeIntegration` is set to `false`, and `contextIsolation` is set to `true`, and that's pretty much it (besides setting the width, height of the window, etc.).

Comment: I realized my mistake. Instead of using an `on` event, I just called `windowWithTheButton.webContents.send('opened-window');` directly.